# decimal formatting in sql query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query as below:

```
Select price from myTable;
```

This returns value `'22.50'`

However, I need the format as `5.8 bytes` in my program.

That is my String value should be `'00022.50000000'` and not `'22.50'`

Is there a way to achieve this directly in SQL ?

Comment: Does it have to be done in sql or could your program which is querying the database format the number? A brief look is not promising for what DB2 can do natively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From docs, I think you want [CHAR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000777.htm)( [DECIMAL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000791.htm)( 22.50, 13, 8 ) )

I have no DB2 instance to play with so can't verify. These functions are not [ANSI SQL](http://sqlnut.atw.hu/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-4.html), they are DB2 specific.

Comment: yeah, this could work. see: http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/597799-how-convert-double-string-no-decimal-separators