# DB2 Format decimals with custom precision

Tags: format, db2, decimal

I can write the following query for Microsoft SQL Server and it working fine:

```
SELECT 
   STR(Facts.decimal_value,FormattingSettings.length,FormattingSettings.precision)
FROM 
   Facts,FormattingSettings
```

As result i get values formatted with custom precision (FormattingSettings there is one row table) and can changing the formatting dynamically.

It is possible to do same thing for DB2 (9.5)?

The answers for similar questions (like [decimal formatting in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696496/decimal-formatting-in-sql-query)) had used only the integer constant as precision.

Comment: I try 
     SELECT DECIMAL(Facts.decimal_value,15,FormattingSettings.precision)

and get an error:
SQL0123N The parameter in position n in the function name must be a constant or a keyword.

Comment: Of course I need the character representation of decimal. But CHAR and DIGITS built-in functions don't allow formatting of result.